# Update/Modify multiple DNS A type records with same private IPv4 address in Azure using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-dns

I would like to update or modify existing multiple DNS 'A' type records with same one private IP address using powershell.

Can someone help me or advise me on this please, would be a great help. Thank you.

So far I tried by running below command to update/modify existing one DNS A type record not multiple DNS records using same PIP.

```
$rs = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -Name $dnsrecordname –ZoneName "$zone" -ResourceGroupName "$dnsrg" -RecordType A
$rs.Records[0].Ipv4Address = "$ipAddress"
$setdnsrecord=Set-AzDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs
```

$dnsrecordname this variable has only one DNS record name, so now I want to update/modify DNS records where I have more than 3  records.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you essentially have current records of :

```
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.2.2
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.3.3
```

and you want to change that to :

```
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1
```

If so then that's not possible as you can't have more than one identical record. foo.domain.com can point to multiple IP addresses, and multiple hosts can point to the same IP address.

If not then can you elaborate what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Keith, Thank you for your reply. my requirement was I have three domain records and it has same IP address but I want to apply new IP address to those three records with the same IP as below.

Now, my dns records looks like as below.

`foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.1.1`

Now I would like to apply new IP address using PowerShell and that IP address would be same for 3 records as mentioned below.

I want to change as below.
`foo.domain.com  A  192.168.2.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.2.1
foo.domain.com  A  192.168.2.1`

Comment: @Tanveers Having three entries for an A record with the same value makes no sense. Why would you want to do that? The purpose of multiple values is to provide round-robin (select one value at random) and failover (some clients will retry the next value if the first fails).